Changing the tab inthe TabView based on location?
init() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    self.state = defaults.object(forKey: "State") as? String ?? ""
    self.county = defaults.object(forKey: "County") as? String ?? ""
    self.postalCode = defaults.object(forKey: "PostalCode") as? String ?? ""
    self.locality = defaults.object(forKey: "Locality") as? String ?? ""
}

Inside the TabView {...
        if(state == "NJ") {
            AboutView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("About", systemImage: "info.circle")
                }
        } else {
            ConnectView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Connect", systemImage: "person.2")
                }
        }

The UI always displays the else condition even though I know the mock location is "NJ"
In the class with the @main
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var locationCoordinator = LocationCoordinator()
    
    init() {
        locationCoordinator.locationUpdated = { state, county, postalCode, locality in
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(state, forKey: "State")
            defaults.set(county, forKey: "County")
            defaults.set(postalCode, forKey: "PostalCode")
            defaults.set(locality, forKey: "Locality")
        }
    }


My understanding is you want the user defaults to be the source of truth and you want the location coordinator to update it and have the SwiftUI views read from it. So you could try something like this:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var locationCoordinator = LocationCoordinator()
    @AppStorage("State") private var state = ""

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(state: state)
        }
        .onChange(of: locationCoordinator.state) {
            self.state = locationCoordinator.state
        }
    }
}

Another way would be to pass a binding into the coordinator like this:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject private var locationCoordinator = LocationCoordinator()
    @AppStorage("State") private var state = ""

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(state: state)
        }
        .onAppear {
            locationCoordinator.stateBinding = $state
        }
    }
}

Either way has pros and cons for tests and Previews. Also, if you switch from Combine to async/await there would be no @StateObject anymore, just a .task so that's something worth thinking about.

I used UserDefault because it’s available quickly. Location detection may take some time. If the user launched the app before, we would know they were in NJ or some place else. If they are/were in NJ then we can load the AboutView otherwise some other view

AppStorage is SwiftUI for UserDefault

Where are you getting .stateBinding from? Xcode is telling me it doesn’t exist. Also onAppear is not valid for WindowGroup

You need to implement that, var stateBinding: Binding? But as I said the other way might be better
